# Zalando RFC7807 wrong serializer picked for Status with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jhipster

In a specific case, Jackson picks the wrong serializer for Zalando Problem Status. It picks the `EnumSerializer` instead of the `StatusTypeSerializer` it should. When deserializing, it does take the right one (which is why I have the exception below)

The issue can be reproduced with [this project](https://github.com/henri-tremblay/jacksonissue). Just run `AccountResourceIntTest.testRegisterInvalidLogin`. It doesn't happen in a smaller test case but does reliably on this one.

This is the error if it can be of any help:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Current token
>   (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors  at
>   [Source: [B@2aa85cc4; line: 1, column: 10181]  at [Source:
>   [B@2aa85cc4; line: 1, column: 10180] (through reference chain:
>   org.zalando.problem.DefaultProblem["status"]) Motivation for or Use
>   Case

I don't know the logic of Jackson to select the right serializer. But I know the wrong serializer is used. It doesn't happen on all my tests. However, every constraint validation error fails.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not setting the **httpMessageConverters** to **restUserMockMvc**.

Adding this solved the issue for me :

```
.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters)
```

Comment: You're my hero. And that was a stupid question retrospectively. I got totally misled by the fact that the other `MockMvc` was working. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's confusing because you have to manually set multiple things on the mock (ControllerAdvice, MessageConverter, Filter, etc) to totally replicate the behavior of your Spring app. And it's easy to forget doing that haha.